# How to get Rails 4 activerecord insert sql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to get the sql statement of activerecord dynamically.
e.g

```
pen = Pen.new
pen.description = "HB"
pen_sql = pen.insert_sql
puts pen_sql 
=> "Insert into pens (description) values ('HB')"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create you own method to get the insert statement something like this.

```
def get_insert_sql(from_dbmodel)
  insert_sql = from_dbmodel.class.arel_table.create_insert.tap do |im|
    im.insert(from_dbmodel.send(:arel_attributes_with_values_for_create, from_dbmodel.attribute_names))
  end.to_sql

  return insert_sql     
end

pen = Pen.new
pen.description = "HB"
pen_sql = get_insert_sql(pen)
puts pen_sql 
=> "Insert into pens (description) values ('HB')"
```

Tested in rails 4